# Can I link class/record methods to an external module?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi I can link to external code like so:

```
   {$L 'C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Life64\Lazarus\lib\x86_64-win64\AVXGenerate.o'}

function GenerateQtoP_AVX_32(main, N,W,NW: pointer): byte;
  external name 'AVXGENERATE_$$_GENERATEQTOP_AVX_32$POINTER$POINTER$POINTER$POINTER$$BYTE';
function GeneratePtoQ_AVX_32(main, S,E,SE: pointer): byte;
  external name 'AVXGENERATE_$$_GENERATEPTOQ_AVX_32$POINTER$POINTER$POINTER$POINTER$$BYTE';
procedure ReverseBitsInAllBytes(ReverseMe: pointer);
  external name 'AVXGENERATE_$$_REVERSEBITSINALLBYTES$POINTER';
```

In this case it links to AVX2 assembly code I write in Lazarus.

Is there a way to link member methods of a class or record in this way?

Something like the following pseudocode:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
  public
    procedure DoSomething(x,y: integer) = ExternalMethod;
```

Comment: Well, no. Ok, you can do what David proposes, but that only works if your first parameter is a pointer to such a record or if you can declare them as static class methods. **But take care that you get the calling convention right too!**

Comment: @rudy obviously you've got to match the parameter list, that goes without saying for external functions, but if this is a member function then clearly you will be passing the self pointer to it

Comment: @david: yes but how? OK, if he himslef can add a self parameter to the functions, then fine, although a bit tricky. I personally would simply wrap the DLLfunctions and inline my wrappers.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the `main` parameter is. And does the default FPC Win32 calling convention match the one for Delphi?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It looks like you don't understand the question. There are no DLLs, and since these are member functions the external code is clearly going to accept an instance pointer, because, well, member functions always do.

Comment: Ah, I see, functions in object files. Who says these external functions are member functions? Can you see that from the signatures?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the signature does not show that, because the assembler has no knowledge of the class structure. I simply comment the register usage according to the ABI, and yes, if you compile in Delphi mode the ABI matches. Anyway this is Win64, so it will always match.

Comment: @Rudy Dude, he wants to call a member function and have it jump direct to the external function. How could the external function not have an instance pointer? If he wants to link to a function with no instance pointer he'd use a simple function or a static class method.

Comment: @David: Who says he wants to call a member function? And if the external functions *are* member functions that expect an instance pointer, then the externals are not translated properly, unless `main` is that instance pointer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the Q explicitly asks how to link member functions to external code. Obviously I will make sure all the parameters (hidden and explicit) are all received correctly on the other end.

Comment: @Johan: then your declarations were wrong.

Comment: @Rudy Er, it's in the question!!!!!! You might like to read it.

Comment: @David: no, it isn't. The methods are in Delphi. It was not clear (until Johan clarified) that the external functions are methods too.

Comment: @rudy Judging by the fact that the question has long been answered it seems that it was perfectly clear.

Comment: @David: not to me. Probably because I would never "export" methods as such, especially not between two different languages (FPC and Delphi, in this case).

Comment: Well, if you can't see the need for it then I guess it's pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you want. I think that perhaps the closest you can manage is to implement the method with an assembler jump to the external function:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
  public
    procedure DoSomething(x, y: integer);
  end;

procedure MyRecDoSomething(var Self: TMyRec; x, y: integer); external;

procedure TMyRec.DoSomething(x, y: integer);
asm
  JMP MyRecDoSomething
end;
```

Or you might make an inlined method:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
  public
    procedure DoSomething(x, y: integer); inline;
  end;

procedure MyRecDoSomething(var Self: TMyRec; x, y: integer); external;

procedure TMyRec.DoSomething(x, y: integer);
begin 
  MyRecDoSomething(Self, x, y);
end;
```

When calling `TMyRec.DoSomething`, there is a call followed by a jump for the first version (using `asm`). For the second version (using `inline`) there is a single call directly to the external function.

Comment: Note that the two approaches are not the same. If you inline, then the method that you inline, must have matching parameters between the inner and outer method or the output might get garbled. The `jmp` does not need any parameters.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Still not making any sense to me. It sounds like you are talking about specifics of your code, and not the simplified version seen in this topic.

Comment: Anyway, what you are saying isn't correct. The two variants offered here behave identically. There is a difference in that a call to `TMyRec.DoSomething` results in a call followed by a jump in the first version, and for the inlined version a call to `TMyRec.DoSomething` results in a direct call into the external function. Which is as efficient as possible I think.

Comment: There is a bug in the compiler (Berlin). I'm trying to isolate it using a simple testcase.

Comment: In my XE7 it all behaves just as I describe, and as you would expect

Comment: It works fine as long as long as you declare the parameters for the external function in your Delphi code correctly. If you don't, then things break. I'm still investigating how and when this happens.

Comment: Well, if you declare the external function incorrectly, then the inlining approach cannot work. That's not a compiler bug. That's a bug in your code!